# Do a MySQL Query after a scroll down event

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I want to achieve loading more results when a user continues to trigger scroll down event down to the bottom part of the browser. If my query has 20 rows of result, I want to initially load 5 results, when a user scrolls down, he/she should be able to see 5 more results... And this shall continue until all of the results are loaded and displayed.

Here's the code that I have tried, this will only allow me to display more results once:
Anyone who can help me?

**Javascript:**

```
$.get('load_second.php', function(data) {
$('#result').append(data);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to write it on your own, Paul Irish has a good [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll), or google for "infinite scroll" if that doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a page variable. Initially this variable should be 1. Use this variable to retrieve the next pages and increase it by one with every request.

```
var page = 1;

$.get('load_data.php?page=' + page, function(data) {
   page += 1;
   $('#result').append(data);
});
```

Comment: Something like this should do the trick, although if the underlying data has the potential to change while the user is on the page, you may want to `ORDER BY SomeUniqueField` when pulling results out of the database and pass the highest or lowest value yet seen of SomeUniqueField to the php script in the query string instead of a page number. That way, you avoid any risk of showing the user duplicates.

Comment: That is a start, you would however also have to listen for the scroll-event on the window and decide when you want to trigger a new request to load additional data, in order to fulfill OP's desired solution.

Comment: Thanks. Im going to try this.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson If I'm understanding the OP correctly, he's already got that stuff handled.